# Custom Triangular UICollectionviewCell In collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Normally UICollectionviewcell is of rectangular box shaped and we can modify the appearance in custom UICollectionViewCell , But in my case i want the cell to be of shape triangular or any shape other than simple rectangular, How can i achieve this function?

Answer (score 3):

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    var path = UIBezierPath();
    var mask = CAShapeLayer();




            path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0))
            path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: cell.bounds.size.width-(cell.bounds.size.width/2), y:cell.bounds.size.width-(cell.bounds.size.width/2) ))
            path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: cell.bounds.size.width, y: 0))
            path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

            mask.frame = cell.bounds
            mask.path = path.CGPath
            cell.layer.mask = mask




     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return cell
}
```

[image]

It would be better to bring this masking code to custom cell and than detect where touched and changed a boolean property this is a simple solution ,yes you can go for a better one.

Code in custom cell .

```
   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
         let touch : UITouch! = touches.first

        self.clickedLocation = touch.locationInView(touch.view)

        print(self.clickedLocation.x)
        print(self.clickedLocation.y)

  //put condition on x and y here  and get controller and change boolean property .
    if self.clickedLocation.y < 100
    {

    ( ( UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) as? collectionViewController )?.boole = true
    }
    else
    {
         ( ( UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) as? collectionViewController )?.boole = false
    }
}


}
```

Code in viewController.

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if boole == false{
            print("hello")
        }
        else{
            print("bello")
        }
    }
```

where boole is  a simple Boolean variable in controller.

complete code for custom cell for reference .

```
 import UIKit

    class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
        var clickedLocation = CGPoint()
        var path : UIBezierPath!
        var mask : CAShapeLayer!

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            super.drawRect(rect)

           path = UIBezierPath();
             mask = CAShapeLayer();

            path!.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0))
            path!.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width-(self.bounds.size.width/2), y:self.bounds.size.width-(self.bounds.size.width/2) ))
            path!.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: 0))
            path!.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

            mask!.frame = self.bounds
            mask!.path = path!.CGPath
            self.layer.mask = mask


        }
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFr

omNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
         let touch : UITouch! = touches.first

        self.clickedLocation = touch.locationInView(touch.view)

          if        path.containsPoint(self.clickedLocation)
         {
              ( ( UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) as? collectionViewController )?.boole = true
        }
          else{
              ( ( UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) as? collectionViewController )?.boole = false
        }



    }


}
```

Comment: Please look at the image http://i.imgur.com/RIRGCDw.png ...... i followed your steps but when i click the rest portion of my cell which is white my didselectitem delegate is called ...... which i not supposed to be called if my cell this sliced this way.

Comment: you can use this function      path.containsPoint(self.clickedLocation) to check whether the point is inside the path or outside and than change the value of boole variable . this would be much better than testing x and y .other ways include CGPath hit testing , which maybe needed in case you use path.containsPoint(self.clickedLocation) ,so that you can check for boundary line

Comment: :- I absolutely agreed with you .... we can use path.contain points to check whether the touched point is inside the  the path ....... i just want u to know what i am actually trying to do is make this type of view using UIcollectionview http://i.imgur.com/VGCQcWN.png ..... please suggest me how to achieve this ..... and thanks for your answer .

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html      ,Right now i can't suggest much but  you can use this guide by apple to create different bezier paths.