# CollectionViewCell Draw Rect

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to draw a simple outlined circle inside my collection view cells. For some reason, only the first cell is being draw, the rest are not showing.

```
class UserCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x - 1, y: 41)

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath()
        circularPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: 36, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), clockwise: true)

        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        circularPath.lineWidth = 2
        circularPath.stroke()


    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Collection view cells are configured for display using UICollectionViewDataSource method cellForItemAt(). The cells are reused and won't automatically redraw for each 'new' cell. Instead of overriding draw(rect), add subviews to the cell and configure the subviews in cellForItemAt().

Comment: Ok thank you. I've come across this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871544/custom-triangular-uicollectionviewcell-in-collectionview....  which doesn't work. Either in cellForItemAt() or inside the collectionViewCell as shown in this post

Comment: Assume the first part of this answer is what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define your `center` point differently. The `center` point is specified in points in the coordinate system of its **superview**. Either try convert the cell's `center` point from its superview's coordinate system or use the bounds of the cell instead and adjust the `x` and `y` values accordingly.

```
let center = self.convert(self.center, from: self.superview)

let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
```

[image: CollectionViewCell]

Comment: Yes, I realized this afterwards.

Comment: This works also: let center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)

Answer (score 0):

Created a new class conforming to UIView(), added the bezierPath info inside its draw function. Then subclassed this class inside the collectionView cell. Works as expected.